# JQuery Ajax Get passing parameters

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am working on my first MVC application and am running into a bit of a problem.  I have a data table that when a row is clicked, I want to return the detail from that row.  I have a function set up as:

```
function rowClick(item)
{
    $("#detailInfo").data("width.dialog", 800); 
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "<%= Url.Action("GetDetails", "WarningRecognition")%>",
        data: "",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {//do some stuff...and show results}
 }
```

The problem I am running into is the passing of the "item".  I calls the Controller function that looks like this:

```
public JsonResult GetDetails(string sDetail)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Request.QueryString["sDetail"]);
        Debug.WriteLine("sDetail: " + sDetail);
        var myDetailsDao = new WarnRecogDetailsDao();

        return new JsonResult { Data = myDetailsDao.SelectDetailedInfo(Convert.ToInt32(sDetail)) };
    }
```

But it never shows anything as the the "sDetail".  It does hit the function but nothing is passed to it.

So, I have read where you pass the parameter via the data but I have tried every combination I can think of and it never shows up.  Tried:

```
data: {"item"}
data: {sDetail[item]}
data: {sDetail[" + item + "]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try `{ sDetail: item }`?  The data item name needs to match the action argument or asp.net mvc won't know how to wire things up properly.

Comment: Yes I tried that but it still does not show in the COntroller as anything passed to it.

Comment: @George: Can you post the URL that your get request generates?

Comment: Not sure I understand what you want me to post.

Comment: @George: The `$.ajax(...)` call generates an HTTP GET request, I want you to post the URL of that get request.

Comment: Sorry if I am not understand but in the code I wrote, the $.ajax call is calling the Controller:


public JsonResult GetDetails(string sDetail)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Request.QueryString["sDetail"]);
        Debug.WriteLine("sDetail: " + sDetail);
        var myDetailsDao = new WarnRecogDetailsDao();
        return new JsonResult { Data = 
myDetailsDao.SelectDetailedInfo(Convert.ToInt32(sDetail)) };
    }

Comment: @George: I understand it calls the controller, what URL does it use to get there?

Comment: url: "<%= Url.Action("GetDetails", "WarningRecognition")%>",

Comment: Found the answer: url: "<%= Url.Action("GetDetails", "WarningRecognition")%>?sDetail=" + item,

Answer (score 0):

All i know is the format must be:

```
var data = '{"sDetail":"item"}';
```

It doesn't look like your data is in the format. Have you tried that combination?