# Pass parameters in a Node.js GET Ajax

Tags: ajax, node.js

I would like to send an AJAX request to the router function below with parameters `start` and `end` respectively.

Those variables would influence the results I get back from the request.

```
router.get('/winnerlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    var start = "20140621";
    var end = "20140623";
    db.collection('userlist').find({"timestamp": {"$gte": start, "$lt": end}}).toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});
```

**This is my AJAX GET call**

```
function populateWinners() {

    // Empty content string
    var tableContent = '';

    // jQuery AJAX call for JSON
    $.getJSON( '/users/winnerlist', function( data ) {
    userListData = data;
    console.log(data);
        // For each item in our JSON, add a table row and cells to the content string
        $.each(data, function(){
            tableContent += '<tr>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkshowuser" rel="' + this.id2 + '" title="Show Details">' + this.id2+ '</a></td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.email + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td>' + this.code + '</td>';
            tableContent += '<td><a href="#" class="linkdeleteuser" rel="' + this._id + '">delete</a></td>';
            tableContent += '</tr>';
        });

        // Inject the whole content string into our existing HTML table
        $('#winnerList table tbody').html(tableContent);
    });
};
```

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699753/jquery-ajax-get-passing-parameters), but I haven't figured out how to make it work within Node.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For GET requests, parameters are usually passed in the url's query string  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string . In this case, your AJAX URL should be

> '/users/winnerlist?start=20140621&end=20140623'

Then, on the server side, you can use the variables as:

```
    req.query.start //This equals "20140621"
    req.query.end // This equals "20140623"
```

Comment: I don't understand how this has anything to do with my question. The code gets results from the router as it is

Comment: Oh, in that case, you should put 'start' and 'end' as parameters in the url's query string. Then you can retrieve them on the server side by calling req.query.

Comment: Would it be easy to edit your answer to include and illustrate? I'm rather a newbie and It might help others.